# How to combine multiple rows into one row with different column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have table like this i want to get only one row for given budget id
Here is the data.

INPUT:
[image: input]

OUTPUT:
[image: output]

Comment: You can group the data by BudgetId, but you need to decide how you want to summarize the other columns if you want to display the other columns.  Because you're trying to display the "Initiator" for both 10002 rows in the same cell, how should the "Null" and "2" be handled?  You need to summarize them with an aggregate function like `MIN` or `AVG`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Min/Max` aggregate

```
SELECT MontlyBugetId,
       Min(Initiator),Min(Stage1),Min(Stage2),Min(Stage3),Min(Stage4),Min(StatusId)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY MontlyBugetId
```

If this is your table data, then you need to update the records instead of insert to avoid duplicate records